# How do I change the inner text instead of attributes in config transformations?

Tags: asp.net, web-config-transform

I've been using config transformations a lot, but I'm struggling with one bit: the changing of "inner text" as opposed to attributes.

As an example, I've got the following in a config file (Sitecore's webforms for marketers if anyone's interested):

`<param desc="connection string">Database=sitecore_webforms;Data Source=CHANGEME;user id=CHANGEME;password=CHANGEME;Connect Timeout=30</param>`

and I want to change it to the proper connection string. Usually that would be part of an attribute which I can do fine but in this case it's not.

Is this possible using either the "vanilla" transformations or [Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi)'s SlowCheetah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `Replace` transform. In your case, something like

```
<param desc="connection string" xdt:Transform="Replace">new connection string here</param>
```

You'll need to also add the right `xdt:Locator` attribute, to select the element.